# php merge array issue

Tags: php, arrays, merge

I have a the following array structure

```
array(
 0 => 'productItem' =>array(
         0=> object,
         1=> object 
      )

 1 =>'productItem' =>array(
         0=> object,
         1=> object 
      )
```

which I get as it follows

```
   $products = array();
             for($pages=1; $i <= 3; $pages++){                
              $res = $this->client->myfunc($pages,$other_params);
              $products[] = $res->productItems;
         }
```

what I would like to achive to merge all my ProductItem under one array

```
0 => 'productItem' =>array(
             0=> object,
             1=> object, 
             2=> object,
             3=> object 
)
```

Comment: That's not real array structure: `0 => 'productItem' =>array(..)`. Maybe so: `0 => array('productItem' =>array(..))` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To combine all arrays within your array :

```
$newArray = [];

foreach ($array as $item)
{
    $newArray = array_merge($newArray, $item['productItem']);
}
```

This will output an array of the format :

```
         0=> object,
         1=> object, 
         2=> object,
         3=> object
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but does this really work? If I try this code, the result is only the last 'productItem' array.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$arr = array(
    0 => array(
        'productItem' => array(new stdClass(), new stdClass())
    ),
    1 => array(
        'productItem' => array(new stdClass(), new stdClass())
    )
);

$newArr = array('productItem' => array());
foreach($arr as $subArr) {
    $newArr['productItem'] = array_merge($newArr['productItem'], $subArr['productItem']);
}
print_r($newArr);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [productItem] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                )

            [2] => stdClass Object
                (
                )

            [3] => stdClass Object
                (
                )

        )

)
```